# Keyboard dismiss not working properly when dismiss the view swiftui

Tags: swiftui, keyboard, dismiss, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm trying to dismiss the keyboard when view dismissed but keyboard not dismiss properly, they only hide button but they showing height. More detail please check my code and screenshot.

1. Keyboard shows properly

[image: Screenshot]

2. Go To next Screen when keyboard open and dismiss

[image: Screenshot]

3. Keyboard button hide but show height with background

[image: Screenshot]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var titleDtr: String = ""
    @State private var clearAllText: Bool = false
    @State var updateKeyboard = true
    @State var userProfiles = [""]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            HStack{
                CustomTxtfldForFollowerScrn(isDeleteAcntScreen: .constant(false), text:  $titleDtr, clearAllText: $clearAllText, isFirstResponder: $updateKeyboard, completion: { (reponse) in
                    if titleDtr.count >= 3 {
                        userProfiles.append(titleDtr)
                    }else if titleDtr.count <= 3 {
                        userProfiles.removeAll()
                    }
                }).background(Color.red)
                
                VStack(spacing:0) {
                    List {
                        if userProfiles.count > 0 {
                            ForEach(userProfiles.indices, id: \.self) { indexs in
                                NavigationLink(destination: ShowLoadingText()) {
                                    Text(userProfiles[indexs]).foregroundColor(.blue)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.onDisappear{
                updateKeyboard = false
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

import SwiftUI

struct ShowLoadingText: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack(alignment:.center, spacing: 15) {
                HStack(spacing:10){
                    Group {
                        ProgressView()
                            .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle(tint: Color.white))
                        Text("Loading More Users...")
                    }
                }.foregroundColor(.black)
            }
        }
    }
}




struct CustomTxtfldForFollowerScrn: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var isDeleteAcntScreen: Bool
    @Binding var text: String
    @Binding var clearAllText: Bool
    @Binding var isFirstResponder: Bool
    var completion: (String) -> Void
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<CustomTxtfldForFollowerScrn>) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField(frame: .zero)
        textField.text = text
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        textField.backgroundColor = .clear
        if isDeleteAcntScreen {
            textField.placeholder = "DELETE"
        }else{
            textField.placeholder = "Username"
        }
        textField.returnKeyType = .default
        textField.textColor = .black
        return textField
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> CustomTxtfldForFollowerScrn.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<CustomTxtfldForFollowerScrn>) {
        uiView.text = text
        if isFirstResponder && !context.coordinator.didBecomeFirstResponder  {
            uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
            context.coordinator.didBecomeFirstResponder = true
        }else if clearAllText {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                uiView.text! = ""
                text = ""
                clearAllText = false
            }
        }else if !isFirstResponder {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIApplication.shared.endEditing()
            }
        }
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        var didBecomeFirstResponder = false
        var parent: CustomTxtfldForFollowerScrn
        
        init(_ view: CustomTxtfldForFollowerScrn) {
            self.parent = view
        }
        
        func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.parent.text = textField.text ?? ""
                self.parent.completion(textField.text!)
            }
        }
        
        func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
            return true
        }
    }
}

import UIKit

extension UIApplication {
    func endEditing() {
        sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the alternative way to dismissing the keyboard.

First, remove the main queue.

```
func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<CustomTxtfldForFollowerScrn>) {
    uiView.text = text
    if isFirstResponder && !context.coordinator.didBecomeFirstResponder  {
        uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
        context.coordinator.didBecomeFirstResponder = true
    }else if clearAllText {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            uiView.text! = ""
            text = ""
            clearAllText = false
        }
    }else if !isFirstResponder { // < -- From here
        UIApplication.shared.endEditing()
    }
}
```

and then update `updateKeyboard` on `ShowLoadingText()` appear.

```
ForEach(userProfiles.indices, id: \.self) { indexs in
    NavigationLink(destination: ShowLoadingText().onAppear() { updateKeyboard = false }) { // <-- Here
        Text(userProfiles[indexs]).foregroundColor(.blue)
    }
}
```

Remove `onDisappear` code.